# Please can you tell me what is the difference between Wanderwege and Wanderpfade?

Tags: meaning

I have a German language hiking book for the Westweg (Pforzheim-Basel).  The book shows the type of walking in each stage and has percentrages to be walked in each stage, as follows:

- Hartbelag xx%
- Wanderwege xx%
- Wanderpfade xx%.

I see that Hartbelag means tarmac roads and pathways but can find no difference in dictionary definitions between Wanderwege and Wanderpfade.  Please does anyone know the answer to this one?

Comment: The dictionaries should show a difference between _Weg_ and _Pfad_.

Comment: It's unspecific by purpose but *Hartbelag* usually doesn't mean *tarmac road* in German forests but *macadam pavement*.

Comment: Typical *Hartbelag*: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DSC05537a-Feinschotterweg.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Wanderpfade*](https://www.freiburg-entdecken.de/wp-content/uploads/wanderpfad-schlucht.jpg) are typically cross country routes. I don't know the *Westweg* but in most cases *Wanderpfade* are small and narrow paths.

However, [*Wanderwege*](http://www.wanderwegweiser.de/cms2/media/contentbuilder/upload-wanderwege/GEO_Wanderweg_im_Brexbachtal.jpg) are common routes through forests which are wider and easier to hike.

Comment: +1. *Wanderpfade* usually have steeper slopes and more bends. They are not suited for biking or for people with disabilities. Some *Wanderpfade* that are very steep may also be called *Steig* or *Stieg*.